# Uniquely Ergodic Transformation on compact groups

Tags: dynamical-systems, topological-groups, ergodic-theory, topological-dynamics

I am currently reading Einsiedler & Ward's book *Ergodic Theory with a view towards Number Theory* (GTM259) and am stuck at one of the exercises:

> **Exercise 4.3.2 (p.109):** Let $T: X \to X$ be a surjective homomorphism on a compact group $X$. Then $T$ is uniquely ergodic iff $|X| = 1$.

Any help or hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The identity element is kept fixed. So, you have its delta measure as a T-invariant probability. Is there any other?

Comment: Indeed, if $x$ is a fixed point of $T$, then the delta measure on $x$ will give a T-invariant measure. But it is not obvious to me that T necessarily admitts fixed points other than the identity when $|X| > 1$

Comment: There might be no other invariant points. But there might be other T-invariant measures. Since the space is compact, you can iterate and average any other measure and get a T-invariant limit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov%E2%80%93Bogolyubov_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dirac function $\delta_e$ at the origin is invariant by a morphism of a compact group. Its support is the set $\{e\}$, where $e$ is the identity element of the group.

A compact group admits a unique left invariant probability measure, called the Haar measure. You can check that it is invariant by any surjective morphism.
The Haar measure is of full support.

If a surjective morphism is uniquely ergodic, then these two measures are equal. So are their supports. Hence $X$ is equal to $\{e\}$.